# Getting MIN value from array based on another value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Whats the best way to get each of the "Carrier"'s lowest rate?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Method] => SMART_POST
            [Title] => Smart Post
            [Price] => 8.58
            [Carrier] => fedex
            [Carrier Title] => Fedex
            [Description] =>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Method] => GROUND_HOME_DELIVERY
            [Title] => Home Delivery
            [Price] => 12.34
            [Carrier] => fedex
            [Carrier Title] => Fedex
            [Description] =>
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Method] => FEDEX_EXPRESS_SAVER
            [Title] => Express Saver
            [Price] => 16.25
            [Carrier] => fedex
            [Carrier Title] => Fedex
            [Description] =>
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Method] => FEDEX_2_DAY
            [Title] => 2 Day
            [Price] => 20.49
            [Carrier] => fedex
            [Carrier Title] => Fedex
            [Description] =>
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [Method] => PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT
            [Title] => Priority Overnight
            [Price] => 32.17
            [Carrier] => fedex
            [Carrier Title] => Fedex
            [Description] =>
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [Method] => 4
            [Title] => Standard Post
            [Price] => 8.76
            [Carrier] => usps
            [Carrier Title] => United States Postal Service
            [Description] =>
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [Method] => 1
            [Title] => Priority Mail 3-Day
            [Price] => 10.25
            [Carrier] => usps
            [Carrier Title] => United States Postal Service
            [Description] =>
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [Method] => 3
            [Title] => Priority Mail Express 2-Day
            [Price] => 38.8
            [Carrier] => usps
            [Carrier Title] => United States Postal Service
            [Description] =>
        )

)
```

With the above array the result would be

fedex Smart Post 8.58
usps Standard Post 8.76

Comment: start with a foreach loop

Comment: I have some working code, it's just horribly inefficient and hard to debug, I'm asking for the best option.

Comment: I didn't understand your requirement. You told you need the "lowest" rate. The "lowest" rate is only one value, but you are telling in the explanation for 2 values. Am I missing something?

Comment: Lowest based off of carrier.

Comment: foreach, create array for each carrier, sort that

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$arr = Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            'Method' => 'SMART_POST',
            'Title' => 'Smart Post',
            'Price' => '8.58',
            'Carrier' => 'fedex',
            'Carrier Title' => 'Fedex',
            'Description' =>''
        ),

    1 => Array
        (
            'Method' => 'GROUND_HOME_DELIVERY',
            'Title' => 'Home Delivery',
            'Price' => '12.34',
            'Carrier' => 'fedex',
            'Carrier Title' => 'Fedex',
            'Description' =>''
        ),

    2 => Array
        (
            'Method' => 'FEDEX_EXPRESS_SAVER',
            'Title' => 'Express Saver',
            'Price' => '16.25',
            'Carrier' => 'fedex',
            'Carrier Title' => 'Fedex',
            'Description' =>''
        ),

    3 => Array
        (
            'Method' => 'FEDEX_2_DAY',
            'Title' => '2 Day',
            'Price' => '20.49',
            'Carrier' => 'fedex',
            'Carrier Title' => 'Fedex',
            'Description' =>''
        ),

    4 => Array
        (
            'Method' => 'PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT',
            'Title' => 'Priority Overnight',
            'Price' => '32.17',
            'Carrier' => 'fedex',
            'Carrier Title' => 'Fedex',
            'Description' =>''
        ),

    5 => Array
        (
            'Method' => 4,
            'Title' => 'Standard Post',
            'Price' => '8.76',
            'Carrier' => 'usps',
            'Carrier Title' => 'United States Postal Service',
            'Description' =>''
        ),

    6 => Array
        (
            'Method' => 1,
            'Title' => 'Priority Mail 3-Day',
            'Price' => '10.25',
            'Carrier' => 'usps',
            'Carrier Title' => 'United States Postal Service',
            'Description' =>''
        ),

    7 => Array
        (
            'Method' => 3,
            'Title' => 'Priority Mail Express 2-Day',
            'Price' => '38.8',
            'Carrier' => 'usps',
            'Carrier Title' => 'United States Postal Service',
            'Description' =>''
        )

);
usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['Price'] - $b['Price'];
});
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: A good start, but only does the lowest.  I need the lowest of each.  I guess I could make two arrays from the data based off the carrier.

Comment: function sortr($a, $b) {
 return $a['Price'] - $b["Price"];
}
usort($rates, "sortr");  
$fst = array_shift($rates);
while ($fst['Carrier']==$rates[0]['Carrier']){
 array_shift($rates);
}